# I cannot use 2 schemas with the same name in mongoose on 2 different connections because only one the first one is used?

Tags: connection, mongoose

```
var mongodbHost = 'mongodb://localhost:9000/';
var connectionA = require('mongoose').createConnection(mongodbHost + 'A', function(err){
    var schema = require(path.resolve(__dirname, 'migrations', 'v01_00_001', 'models', 'index')).schemas.Serial;
    debugger;
    connectionA.model('Test', schema);
    console.log('First check:', schema.statics.___XXX === connectionA.models.Test.___XXX);
}.bind(this));

var connectionB = require('mongoose').createConnection(mongodbHost + 'B', function(err){
    var schema = require(path.resolve(__dirname, 'models', 'index')).schemas.Serial;  
    debugger;
    connectionB.model('Test', schema);
    console.log('First check:', schema.statics.___XXX === connectionA.models.Test.___XXX);
    console.log('Second check:', schema.statics.___XXX === connectionB.models.Test.___XXX);
}.bind(this));
// output is true, false, false

    // While it should be: true, false, true
```

Anybody knows what I might do?
The problem is that when I do the first require('mongoose') I get a new mongoose instance, therefore the rest of the requires will also get the same instance. And mongoose shares the schemas between connections :s

any help is appreciated,
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give the models different names, but still use the same collection name for both:

```js
connectionA.model('TestA', schema, 'Tests');
...
connectionB.model('TestB', schema, 'Tests');
```

Comment: well it's great by I really needed the model with the same name.. In this case the collection name changes the physical collection/table, right? but when I'm trying to use connectionA.models I should do ".TestA" and not just ".Tests"

Comment: @Totty I guess I'm missing why you care what the model name is since that's just a Mongoose artifact.  Looks like you found a solution though.

Comment: Because I need to do connection.models.ModelName. As the "ModelName" is actually used. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1211

```
var mongooseA = new (require('mongoose').Mongoose)();
var mongooseB = new (require('mongoose').Mongoose)();
```

then create connection 2 connections...